# Why is form submit message displaying all characters from my index.html file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

When my message is submitted it goes to my email address and works fine, but the message success notification doesn't display 'Your message was sent successfully.', instead it displays all of the lines of code within my index file.

I think it has something to do with *style="display: none"*.

Any idea how to show the 'Your message has been sent' message?

***index.html***

```
            <div class="col-lg-5 mx-auto">
              <div class="contact-form">
                <div class="container"> 
                    <form class="contact-form" method="post" action="mail.php">    

                    <!-- form message -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                              <div class="alert alert-success contact__msg" style="display: none" role="alert">
                              Your message was sent successfully.
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <!-- end message -->

                    <!-- form element -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><strong>Name</strong></label>
                              <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><strong>Email</strong></label>
                              <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><strong>Message</strong></label>
                              <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Message" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-paper-plane"></button></span>
                    <!-- end form element -->
                    </form>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

***mail.php***

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        # FIX: Replace this email with recipient email
        $mail_to = "*myemail*@gmail.com";

        # Sender Data
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," ") , strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"])));
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($subject) OR empty($message)) {
            # Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        # Mail Content
        $content = "Name: $name\n";
        $content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        # email headers.
        $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        # Send the email.
        $success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $content, $headers);
        if ($success) {
            # Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            # Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong, we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        # Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

***main.js***

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var form = $('.contact-form'),
        message = $('.contact__msg'),
        form_data;

    // Success function
    function done_func(response) {
        message.fadeIn().removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
        message.text(response);
        setTimeout(function () {
            message.fadeOut();
        }, 100000);
        form.find('input:not([type="submit"]), textarea').val('');
    }

    // fail function
    function fail_func(data) {
        message.fadeIn().removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-success');
        message.text(data.responseText);
        setTimeout(function () {
            message.fadeOut();
        }, 100000);
    }

    form.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form_data
        })
        .done(done_func)
        .fail(fail_func);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: *"I think it has something to do with style="display: none"."* - Did you try and remove it? You'll see that that is what the problem is. Voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: Yes, once I remove it then no message appears. Just the blank space of where it would have fitted in.

Comment: you had the javascript tag included earlier and I removed it since there was none to be found. If you have some to share with us, you will have to update your post and add the tag and the code; there's also possible CSS missing, so check your stylesheet/rules. One thing though; I noticed 2 underscores here `contact__msg` and it *could* have something to do with this if the class only has the one. You should also close it off `style="display: none;"`. Look at your developer console also.

Comment: contact__msg is correct and I put style="display: none;" into my CSS file. I have now included the main.js script also. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome. You have 2 of the same display attributes. I'd try `display: inline;` for the one in your div or `display: block;`.

Comment: so, did what I suggested above work? ^

Comment: Unfortunately not. Tried every variation of 'display:' and it is still showing all characters from my index file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the success function you specify the response but not the text to display.
e.g: message.text(response.??);

The field that contains the message from the back end script is not included so I’m guessing the issue is here. display:none is not the issue...